# The exact security issue behind new Buffer()

Tags: node.js, buffer

All know by now that using the Buffer constructor is deprecated in latest Node versions.

```
var buff = new Buffer();  // Deprecation warning!!
```

The warning says that there is a security issue with the constructor. I was trying to find out the exact security issue behind this warning, but failed.

What is the exact security issue behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4660):

> If an attacker can make your program call the `Buffer` constructor
>   with a `Number` argument, then they can make it allocate uninitialized
>   memory from the node.js process. This could potentially disclose TLS
>   private keys, user data, or database passwords.
>
> When the `Buffer` constructor is passed a `Number` argument, it
>   returns an **UNINITIALIZED** block of memory of the specified size.
>   ...

Comment: This means any language which produce published application shouldn't return uninitialized blocks. Thanks.